# How to get rid of bandicoot around house

Tags: home, pest-control

How to get rid of badicoot around the house.

There are many bandicoots along the border of our house creating holes and every night they dig lot of mud out around the house.

Using poison to kill them doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Similar: [How to eliminate rats from kitchen?](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/3725/how-to-eliminate-rats-from-kitchen) and [How to get mice out of the ceiling?](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2338/how-to-get-mice-out-of-the-ceiling).

Comment: Are they similar (e.g. in behaviour) to rats?

Comment: Bandicoots!  You must be in Australia.

Comment: Also consider asking at Gardening SE, where they know a lot about pest control

Answer (score 2):

Get a dog.  We had a Collie dog who made it her business to find and kill every mole she could possibly find.

Think about it.  The dog stays outside, the dog patrols its property.  The dog keeps away all the bandicoots, and cats, and rats, and everything else you don't want around.

Answer (score 1):

I had to see what a bandicoot is. Thinking about it, what I would try is an electric fence/wire set low to the ground. You would need to clear an area around the wire so grass and weeds don't touch it. The wire would only have to be present a few days, then removed, allowing stakes holding the wire to be temporary rather than permanent. These are small animals, so be humane and use low voltage, but if it does not work, try a little more voltage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which state you live in but in NSW it's illegal to kill or trap bandicoots. There are a few things you can try to deter them-

1. You can try using chicken manure or something with a strong ammonia smell- they don't like the smell of ammonia
2. You can use large floodlights. They'll stay away from well lit areas as they don't like light

Failing that you could always try some fine wire fencing. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing next:

- Pack the soil with a lawn (or garden) roller: this will make it harder for them to “swim” through the packed soil, causing them to move elsewhere inside your garden where they don’t do much damage.
- Eliminate their primary food source by applying insecticides to kill worms, grubs, and billbugs.

Apart from all described methods You can also try setting mole traps(it's pretty much the same) and check out the [source](https://getting-rid-of-ground-moles.com/#control) to find more info on how to manage your problem, maybe you'll find a solution there.